# Tensorflow word2vec InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match

Tags: tensorflow, word2vec

I am using [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/embedding/word2vec_optimized.py) code to train a word2vec model. I am trying to train it incrementally, with using `saver.restore()`. I am using new data after restoring the model. Since vocabulary size for the old data and new data are not the same, I got an exception like this:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [28908,200] rhs shape= [71291,200]
```

Here `71291` is vocabulary size for the old data and `28908` is for new data.

It gets the vocabulary words from the `train_data` file [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/embedding/word2vec_optimized.py#L180), and constructs the network model using size of the vocabulary. I thought that if I could set vocabulary size the same for my old data and new data, I can solve this problem.

So, my question is: Can I do that in this code? As far as I understand, I cannot reach `skipgram_word2vec()` function.

Or, is there any other way of solving this issue in this code beside what I thought? If it is not possible using this code, I will try other ways for my purpose.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Having taken a look at the source of [`word2vec_optimized.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/embedding/word2vec_optimized.py) I'd say you will need to change the code there. It operates by opening a text file right up front as "training data". For your purposes, you have to change the `build_graph` method and allow it to get an option to set all that data ( words, counts, words_per_epoch, current_epoch, total_words_processed, examples, labels, opts.vocab_words, opts.vocab_counts, opts.words_per_epoch ) when initializing, and not from a text file.

Then you need to merge the two text files, and load them once, to produce the vocabulary. Then save all the data above, and use that to restore the network at each subsequent run.

If you use more than 2 texts, you need to include all the text you plan to use in the first data to produce the vocabulary, however.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, I did split my text file into parts, because my machine cannot process that amount of data at once. My intention was training a portion and add another data to resume the training, but I came accross with this problem. I thought that if there is a way to set a vocabulary size, like take the most frequent 100,000 words only, I could construct the same network for all my texts.

Comment: That's doable but then you have to make those changes in the `word2vec_optimized.py` code itself. A theoretical question is how will the same network perform with changing vocabularies, however.